# register spec tests with Mocha and ts-node

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, ts-node

I have a project running with node and typescript.

The project covers different functional areas, and the folder structure reflects such division being something like

```
src
   area-1
      functional-subarea-1-1
         function-1-1-1.ts
         function-1-1-1.spec.ts
   area-2
      function-2-1.ts
      function-2-1.spec.ts
```

In **package.json** I have configured a script to run tests such as

```
"test": "mocha -r ts-node/register src/**/*.spec.ts"
```

With such configuration though only tests at the first sublevel of the project directory get executed (i.e. only function-2-1.spec.ts).

If I want to execute all the tests in my project, I have to create a different script such as

```
"test": "mocha -r ts-node/register src/**/*.spec.ts src/**/**/*.spec.ts"
```

which means that if I increase the depth of my project structure I have to update the script.

Is there a simpler way to tell mocha to consider all tests independent from the depth of the subfolders?